# Creating nullable data types in c#

Tags: c#, nullable

I have a data type called

```
public enum Gender { Male, Female }
```

But some case i need to pass the vale for the gender as empty. So how can i create **nullable** Gender in C#

Comment: @nasmifive: This won't work without adding making the variable explicitly nullable

Comment: @nasmifive: I suppose samadhi wish to have some Database-like behaviour. In databases you can have some fields being "not set" i.e. null. I can even imagine some scenarios where you can have gender not set, e.g. police have found some human remains and they don't surely now was it male of female (it's awful but it's just an example of scenario where you can have gender not set).

Answer (score 8):

Either

```
Gender? myGender = null;
```

Or

```
Nullable<Gender> myGender = null;
```

The first variant is exactly the same as the second, but it just C# syntactic sugar to ease the readability of nullable variables.

Answer (score 4):

> have a data type called  public enum
>   Gender = {Male, Female}; But some case
>   i need to pass the vale for the gender
>   as empty

Actually medically there are more than two genders. Anyhow, besides....

`Nullable<Gender>`.... you dont need that.

`Gender.Undefined = 0` is valid AND needed as per best practice. Atually `Gender.Nothing` is required per .NET enum coding guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can create [`Nullable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx) types in C#

```
Nullable<Gender>
```

or short:

```
Gender?
```

Answer (score 0):

If the "Unspecified" gender should be handled by your application like any other genders, then it is often useful to do it this way:

```
public enum Gender
{
  Unspecified,
  Male, 
  Female,
}
```

Note that in that case, "Unspecified" will be the default value of the enum since its value is zero/0. So when declaring an Gender variable without assigning a value to it it will be automatically "Unspecified".